# window.parent.location.href not working with ajaxcontroltoolkit in asp.net

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit, registerstartupscript, clientscript

I am using iframe to open new .aspx page from parent page. child page is using ajaxcontroltoolkit(ajax CalendarExtender). Now on form submit, I want to close iframe and return to parent page. For that I am using following code.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptid", window.parent.location.href='ViewVendors.aspx'", true);
```

This works file if I remove ajax control from child page but does not work with ajax control.
I want to use calenderExtender and iframe both. How can I use it and what is the problem for such so called abnormal behavior.

This is the code for my submit button event handler.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        objVendor.VendorID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        objVendor.Name = txtName.Text;
        objVendor.BillingAddress = txtBillingAddress.Text;
        objVendor.ShippingAddress = txtShippingAddress.Text;
        objVendor.ContactPersonName = txtContactPerson.Text;
        objVendor.ContactNumber = txtContactNumber.Text;
        objVendor.EmailID = txtEmailID.Text;
        objVendor.VendorSinceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtVendorDate.Text);
        objVendor.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(rdblStatus.SelectedValue);
        objVendor.Logo = FileUpload();
        int intResult = objVendor.UpdateVendor();
        if (intResult > 0)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "window.parent.location.href='ViewVendors.aspx'", "scriptid", true);
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptid", "window.parent.location.href='ViewVendors.aspx'", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        lblMessage.CssClass = "ERROR";
    }
}
```

//Edit
Now my code works fine as long as I am not adding calender extender to the child page.
When I add calender extender in child page it shows error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)". If I remove calender extender, again it works well. By doing some googling, I found that <% %> in Javascript tag is creating problem. How can I solve it and why calender control is creating problem in such cases?

Here is the code for my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadStarted() {
        $get("imgDisplay").style.display = "none";
    }
    function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
        //  var imgPhoto = $get("#imgPhoto");
        var imgPhoto = document.getElementById('<%=imgPhoto.ClientID %>');
        imgDisplay.src = "images/loader.gif";
        imgPhoto.style.display = "none";
        imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:100px;width:100px";
            imgDisplay.src = img.src;
        };
        img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + args.get_fileName();

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your JavaScript using the [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) instance on your page - which you should already have if you're using AJAX.  It has its own [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method that you can use.

Comment: Instance of scriptmanager is not showing RegisterStartupScript method. Can you please explain in detail with example? Here is the instance of scriptmanatger                         <asp:ScriptManager ID="manager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: Its a static method, so you'd call it like in code like this: `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...)`

Comment: ..I wrote like this ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "window.parent.location.href='ViewVendors.aspx", "scriptid", true); Still its not working. I want to redirect at ViewVendors.aspx page which is parent page. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: You transposed the key and script arguments and you forgot a single quote after ViewVendors.aspx.  Should be: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "scriptid", "window.parent.location.href='ViewVendors.aspx'", true);`

Comment: I did the same but still not working. Am I missing any parameter or they are misplaced?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? If you view source do you see the JavaScript you're trying to insert?  Are you seeing a 404 error, or some indication that its trying to go the wrong page?  Are you seeing any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I am not seeing any kind of error. The page remains as it is after I submit the form. Javascript is not visible in page source.

Comment: Just to be clear, the page source you looked at was the iframe's source and not the parent page's right?  Your submit button is in the iframe and the submit button's handler is where you're trying to inject the JavaScript from, correct?

Comment: I saw source for both the pages. In none of the page javascript is visible. Yes, Submit button is in ifram(In child page) and I am trying to inject javascript in button click event.

Comment: Are you sure that your key value "scriptid" is unique?  Can you post you submit button event handler code as an edit to your question?

Comment: I have edited my question with the code. I dont have idea what is "scriptid".

Comment: "scriptid" is what you typed as the key value in the RegisterStartupScruipt call.  Also, in your posted handler you still have the scriptid and JavaScript arguments reversed.  The script id comes before the JavaScript.

Comment: Still its not working. I made necessary correction. I replace my code with what you suggested in comment. Tried by replacing "scriptid" with "scriptid1" but still not working.

Comment: Two more suggestions: (1) Try `this` instead of `this.Page` as the first argument to RegisterStartupScript. (2) Place a semi-colon after your JavaScript: `"window.parent.location.href='ViewVendors.aspx';"`.

Comment: ..Please review edited my question. Now I am getting new error if I add CalenderExtender

Comment: Try using <%#...%> instead of <%=...%> in your script element.  You will need to call `Page.Header.DataBind();` on your page's load handler.